# 6 видов причастия

Tags: грамматика, причастия

Можно выделить 6 видов причастий:

1. Действительные причастия несовершенного вида. Настоящего времени.
2. Действительные причастия несовершенного вида. Прошедшего времени.
3. Действительные причастия совершенного вида. Прошедшего времени.
4. Страдательные причастия несовершенного вида. Настоящего времени.
5. Страдательные причастия несовершенного вида. Прошедшего времени.
6. Страдательные причастия совершенного вида. Прошедшего времени.

Пытаюсь привести примеры всех шести видов для 4-x глаголов: отдавать / давать / отдать / дать. (Почему-то слово "давающий" не проходит орфографическую проверку. Кстати, почему?)

1. Действительные причастия несовершенного вида. Настоящего времени:

   Отдавающий / Давающий / Отдающий / Дающий
2. Действительные причастия несовершенного вида. Прошедшего времени:

   Отдававший / Дававший / Отдавший / Давший
3. Действительные причастия совершенного вида. Прошедшего времени:

   ??? / ??? / ??? / ???
4. Страдательные причастия несовершенного вида. Настоящего времени:

   Отдаваемый / Даваемый / ??? / ???
5. Страдательные причастия несовершенного вида. Прошедшего времени:

   ??? / ??? / ??? / ???
6. Страдательные причастия совершенного вида. Прошедшего времени:

   ??? / ??? / Отданный / Данный

Пожалуйста, дополните и поправьте таблицу, объясняя, почему.
Впишите правильные слова вместо знаков вопроса или обоснуйте их несуществование.

Comment: В каждом пункте должно быть только два  причастия. "Отдавающий" и "давающий" не существуют в языке. "Отдавший"  и "давший" относятся к **совершенному** виду. Несов, вид : отдававший, дававший.

Comment: Оказывается не во всех пунктах по два причастия. В 5 пункте вообще ноль получается или нет? Почему так?

Comment: Насчет слова давающий. Очевидно оно более соответствует структуре языка чем слово дающий. Почему? Да потому что дающий это причастие настоящего времени от глагола давать (у глагола "дать" просто нету причастий в настоящем времени). А раз оно произошло от слова давать, то почему тогда не писать давающий вместо дающий??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Шесть видов причастий (или любое другое количество видов), конечно,  можно при желании выделить, но лучше этого не делать, потому что **их всего четыре**.

Классификация причастий делается **по их форме**, то есть по суффиксам, и поэтому выделяется 4 вида причастий: действительные и страдательные причастия настоящего и прошедшего времени.

**Действительные причастия настоящего времени** образуются  от глаголов несовершенного вида. **Страдательные причастия настоящего времени** образуются от переходных глаголов несовершенного вида.

**Действительные причастия прошедшего времени образуются от любых глаголов** (переходных и непереходных, совершенного и несовершенного вида).

Большинство **страдательных причастий прошедшего времени** образуются от  переходных глаголов совершенного вида.

Действие-признак, которое выражает причастие, согласуется по времени с действием, выраженным глаголом-сказуемым.

Подробно можно почитать в учебнике, например: http://bugabooks.com/book/226-sovremennyj-russkij-yazyk/215--198-formy-prichastij-i-ix-obrazovanie.html

**Примечания**

1) Конечно, следует приветствовать творческий подход к изучению предмета, **но при этом нельзя не учитывать (обходить стороной)  базовые знания по изучаемой теме.** Иначе это будет детской игрой, а не серьезным занятием, пустой тратой своего и чужого времени. Сначала изучите то, что признано всеми, а потом ищите самостоятельный путь, где, возможно, вы сделаете интересные для себя открытия.

2) **Работайте с реальными текстами**. Классика или современность, разговорная или книжная речь, но эти тексты должны иметь реальное содержание. Изучать грамматику с помощью выдуманных предложений не имеет никакого смысла. И зачем их выдумывать, если в Интернете вы можете найти любые примеры для грамматического анализа.

Comment: Спасибо! Только "Действие-признак, которое выражает причастие, согласуется по времени с действием, выраженным глаголом-сказуемым" обсуждали в https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/445704  и пришли к выводу что согласованность времени не нужна.

Comment: Разве можно однозначно доверять обсуждению на форуме, ведь люди часто просто высказывают свое  собственное мнение. Хорошо, если при этом дается ссылка на источник .  Вот, к примеру, фраза из учебника, указанного в ссылке в моем ответе: "Причастия настоящего времени выражают одновременность действий, обозначенных причастием и глаголом-сказуемым". У меня дома есть вузовский учебник, где расписаны временные отношения со сказуемым для всех причастий. Вы такие книги читайте, материал онлайн можно найти в Сети без труда. А на форуме лучше обсуждать частные неясные вопросы. Успехов Вам.

Answer (score 0):

Благодаря М_Г и хорошему сайту [https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/дать](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C), [https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/давать](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

кое-что прояснилось, но не всё!
Получается такая таблица:

1. Совершенные глаголы отдать / дать образуют 2 вида причастия:

   1.1. Действительные причастия совершенного вида. Прошедшего времени:

   Отдавший / Давший

   1.2. Страдательные причастия совершенного вида. Прошедшего времени:

   Отданный / Данный
2. Несовершенные глаголы отдавать / давать образуют 4 вида причастия:

   2.1. Действительные причастия несовершенного вида. Настоящего времени:

   Отдающий / Дающий. 
   Любопытно что эти глаголы произошли от "давать" хотя больше похожи на "дать"

   2.2. Действительные причастия несовершенного вида. Прошедшего времени:

   Отдававший / Дававший

   2.3. Страдательные причастия несовершенного вида. Настоящего времени:

   Отдаваемый / Даваемый

   2.4. Страдательные причастия несовершенного вида. Прошедшего времени:

   не сущ / не сущ. Почему???

Comment: Кажется понял почему не существуют страдательные причастия несовершенного вида, прошедшего времени от глагола "Давать". Потому что они вообще никогда не существуют как класс. Ни для каких глаголов. См rus.stackexchange.com/a/45553/190920 Таким образом всего типов причастий оказывается не 6 а 5!