# Нужна ли согласованность времен между сказуемым и причастием-определителем у дополнения?

Tags: грамматика, причастия

Правильны ли предложения с точки зрения грамматики?

1.
"Я разговариваю с сестрой, готовившей пирог вчера утром" (но так и не приготовившей).

2.
"Я разговариваю с сестрой, готовившей пирог".

3.
"Я разговариваю с единственной родившей сестрой".

4.
"Я разговаривала с сестрой, готовящей пирог".

Здесь вроде как несогласованность по времени сказуемого и причастия-определителя.
Но с другой стороны, почему мы требуем от определителя "родившей" какое-то конкретное время? Ведь определитель связан только с "сестрой", но никак не со сказуемым "разговариваю".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, грамматически с этим предложениями все в порядке. Семантически, конечно, есть различия. Но предложение 2 тоже не выглядит странным, особенно если мы добавим немножко контекста.

> На кухне гора грязной посуды, неубранный миксер, распахнутая духовка.
>   Утро. **Я разговариваю с сестрой, готовившей пирог** до поздней ночи и
>   вставшей сегодня рано, чтобы подать нам завтрак.

От определения "родившей" мы требуем не время, а совершенный вид. Согласитесь, разговаривать с рожающей сестрой - это одно, это женщина в процессе родов, а с родившей - другое. Единственная родившая сестра - это единственная из нескольких ваших сестер, у которой уже есть опыт родов (и, скорее всего, кровный ребенок или двойня, тройня). Если сестра рожала неоднократно, мы скажем "рожавшей". Остальные сестры еще детей не имеют или воспитывают приемных.

Comment: А нужна ли запятая после "ночи"? Конечно, не по теме, но всё же русский язык обсуждаем. Это же однородные члены, причастия.

Comment: Убрала пока, но в справочник посмотрю. Не совсем причастия, а причастные обороты, соединенные союзом "и", но однородные, да.

Comment: Ясно, значит "временем" причастия можно крутить как-угодно. Я буду рожавшей сестрой. Я буду рожающей сестрой. Я есть рожающая сестра. Я есть рожавшая сестра. Я была рожающей сестрой. Я была рожавшей сестрой. И даже : Я буду сестрой, которая будет, которая будет рожать.

Comment: @user190920, грамматически - да, а логически и лексически - уже исходя из контекста.

Answer (score 0):

Все же очень просто: попробуйте согласовать времена. Попробуйте сегодня поговорить с сестрой, которая вчера готовила пирог.

Comment: А в чем проблема. Сегодня говорю, вчера она готовила... Ну допустим 2-ое неправильно, хотя почему не понимаю. Но 3-е и 4-е вроде бы нормально звучат?

Comment: Так я об этом и говорю. Сами задали вопрос, сами и ответили. )